# Why i am not getting proper output while create pivot table using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to get record based on on date range and get data in pivot table format
but maybe something wrong, only one day data getting less day record not coming

MySQL QUERY-

```
SELECT number,
if(date= '2022-08-22', status,  null) day1_status,
if(date= '2022-08-23', status,  null) day2_status,
if(date= '2022-08-24', status,  null) day3_status,
if(date= '2022-08-25', status,  null) day4_status
from table where date BETWEEN '2022-08-22' and '2022-08-25'
GROUP by number
```

output -

| number | day1_status | day2_status | day3_status | day4_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | active | null | null | null |
| 20 | active | null | null | null |

above mention output is wrong my expected output is-

| number | day1_status | day2_status | day3_status | day4_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | active | no | active | no |
| 20 | active | active | no | active |

Current mysql table.

| id | number | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | active | 2022-08-22 |
| 2 | 10 | no | 2022-08-23 |
| 3 | 10 | active | 2022-08-24 |
| 4 | 10 | no | 2022-08-25 |
| 5 | 20 | active | 2022-08-22 |
| 6 | 20 | active | 2022-08-23 |
| 7 | 20 | no | 2022-08-24 |
| 8 | 20 | active | 2022-08-25 |

Comment: Please fix the typos in the published query so we have confidence in our start point. GROUPBY, 4Xday1_status, beetween, car_status(which doesn't appear in sample data)?..

Comment: @P.Salmon yes typos error error fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using GROUP BY without an aggregate function.

```
SELECT 
  number,
  max(if(`date`= '2022-08-22', status,  null)) day1_status,
  max(if(`date`= '2022-08-23', status,  null)) day1_status,
  max(if(`date`= '2022-08-24', status,  null)) day1_status,
  max(if(`date`= '2022-08-25', status,  null)) day1_status
from `table` where date BETWEEN '2022-08-22' and '2022-08-25'
GROUP by number
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=220fb17fa65c055cd485ee16d6f84172)